# Group by Similar 2 fields in php?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

How to Group two Similar fields in php?

I tried with GROUP BY DATE(bill.date) , bill.agent_id    but it is not working for me

Table Structure 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvBF0.jpg (table name is bill_agents )
Table Structure 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/38tKh.jpg (table name is bill )

Current Result

```
+---------+----+----+----+-----+----+
|         |  1 |  2 |  3 |   4 |  5 |
+---------+----+----+----+-----+----+
| Agent 1 | 35 |  0 |  0 |   0 |  0 |
| Agent 2 |  0 | 10 |  0 |   0 |  0 |
| Agent 1 |  0 |  0 | 12 |   0 |  0 |
| Agent 3 |  0 |  0 |  0 | 100 |  0 |
| Agent 6 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   9 |  0 |
| Agent 2 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   9 | 14 |
+---------+----+----+----+-----+----+

But I want To get Like The Following

+---------+----+----+----+-----+----+
|         |  1 |  2 |  3 |   4 |  5 |
+---------+----+----+----+-----+----+
| Agent 1 | 35 |  0 | 12 |   0 |  0 |
| Agent 2 |  0 | 10 |  0 |   0 | 14 |
| Agent 3 |  0 |  0 |  0 | 100 |  0 |
| Agent 6 |  0 |  0 |  0 |   9 |  0 |
+---------+----+----+----+-----+----+
```

Php Code pasted below that I am using now .

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="1">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <?php
for ($i=01; $i<=31; $i++)
  {?>
    <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
    <?php

  }
?>
    <td>Total</td>
  </tr>
  <?php 

    $query4 = "SELECT bill.agent_id, bill.date, SUM(bill.amount + bill.cheque) AS total, bill_agents.id,bill_agents.name ".
          "FROM bill, bill_agents ".
          "WHERE bill.agent_id = bill_agents.id AND YEAR(date)  = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE()) ". 
          "GROUP BY bill.agent_id , DATE(bill.date)   ".

              // "GROUP BY bill.agent_id , DATE(bill.date)  ".
              "ORDER BY bill.date ASC";

    $result4 = mysql_query($query4) or die('Error, query failed1'); 
    if  (mysql_num_rows($result4)>0){
    mysql_data_seek($result4, 0);   

?>
  <?php $total_1 = 0;  while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4, MYSQL_ASSOC)){?>
  <?php $date =    $row4['date'];

    $var = $date;
    $date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($var) );
    $date=substr($date, 0, -8); 

    echo $date;

    ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row4['name']; ?></td>
    <?php
for ($i=01; $i<=31; $i++)
  {?>
    <td><?php if ($date == $i) echo $row4['total']; ?></td>
    <?php

  }
?>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } } ?>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="31"></td>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what is your table structure lookingat your query there seems to be more than one table

Comment: Slimier? I assume you mean similar? Edit your post and question

Comment: Table Structure [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/38tKh.jpg)

Comment: There seems to be more than one table in query, you have mentioned link twice but to same table. Where is the structure of another table? Also mention the name of table somewhere in image

Comment: [here is the link for another table](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yvBF0.jpg)  table name is bill_agents

Comment: When creating Questions create tables with http://sqlfiddle.com/ , then people can you help more quicker

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is, you need total amount processed by a agent and in a particular month of year.
Then change your query as follows,

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT b.date,b.agent_id,(SUM(b.amount) + SUM(b.cheque)) AS total,ba.id,ba.name 
FROM bill_agent ba LEFT JOIN bill b ON b.agent_id = ba.id
WHERE YEAR(b.date)  = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(b.date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
GROUP BY b.date";

?>
```